effects of low gravity over many generations
A fleet of Earth colonists arrive at a habitable planet with a lower gravity than Earth's - approx 75%.
A straggler from the fleet arrives ~500 years later (eddies in the time/space continuum - whatever).
Would the relative body makeup of the earlier colonists have inherently atrophied based on the influence of gravitational environment, after 500 years of exposure to a lower gravity environment? So for example, would a child born to a descendant of the original colonists be noticeably frailer than a child born from a new arrival? Or would that level of gravitational difference not affect humans generationally.
Basically, I want the new colonists to appear to have superstrength compared to the current colonists.
(Assume that the journey did not cause the colonists' muscles to atrophy, either through FTL travel, artificial gravity, electric muscle stimulation, whatever.)

If you want new colonists to have super-strength compared to the current colonists, you could have nationally segregated colony ships. The people of New Philippines are going to be pretty surprised when their sister ship Spirit of Sweden shows up full of giants.

I upvoted Monty's answer, it's correct, but let's build on it
Let's consider me vs. Arnold Schwarzenegger in his heyday. He could have picked me up and bounced me around like a basketball — and we both grew up at 1G.
"Super strength" is a point of view that you did not define. You might be thinking about John Carter leaping magnificently into the air in Edgar Rice Burroughs' A Princess of Mars...
Image from Walt Disney's John Carter (2012).
... when the reality is a lot closer to what astronauts experienced on the moon, which is a lot less than 0.75G.
Image from NASA footage from the Apollo 16 lunar mission. Click here to see an astronaut leaping in the moon's 0.16G gravity.
Yes, we could argue about the encumbrance of Apollo space suits, the mass of that pack, etc., etc., but it wouldn't change anything. I agree with Monty that if there's a difference, it would be minor and have more to do with the labor/exercise routines of the earlier colonists than the gravity itself (just like here on Earth). Yes, it would be a contributor... but not to the level of John Carter.
Your problem is that mass is independent of gravity. It takes the same energy to accelerate a 100kg mass to 9.8 m/s whether it's on Earth, on the moon, in space... or on your planet. The difference is that it need only be applied once in space and (ignoring some small details) it keeps going at 9.8m/s forever. On Earth that energy must be re-applied every second to hold the object aloof from Earth's gravity. On your planet it would slowly be climbing toward space. But let's use this as a rough comparison of "strength." The formula for calculating the kinetic energy needed to accelerate a mass is:
$$KE = \frac{m * v^2}{2}$$
Earth's acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 m/s2. Your planet is 75% of that or 7.35 m/s2. Let's ignore the energy needed to lift the mass for a moment and just compare the effort needed to hold the 100kg mass against gravity.
Earth is 4,802 joules per-second. On your planet it's 2,701 joules per-second.
Let's be really generous and call that a 2X bonus. So, if we define "super strength" as 2X, you have your super strength. But let's look at reality. I can hold about 27kg for a minute without growing uncomfortable. A professional weightlifter can hold 100kg+ for a minute. Again, let's be generous... that's a 4X strength difference and a change in gravity isn't even involved. It's just the difference between an athlete and a couch potato. The change in gravity gives us an average benefit of 2X, which means it's only improving an average adult male to 50% of a professional weightlifter.
That's hardly super strength.
(We can do a similar calculation for the energy needed to move an object under the influence of gravity, which uses the equation $F = m*g*distance$, but it'll only show you that there's even less impact in that condition.)
So, no super strength... but you do have one thing. Super stamina! At least for a while. Generations of living on that planet would acclimate the inhabitants to the effort to move things. Their strength will vary as much as hear on Earth, but their ability to stick with an effort over time will reduce without serious stamina training (like training for bicycle distance races). Is it John Carter-style super something? Nope. But it would be impressive, nonetheless.
Conclusion
If you're looking for science-based, I'd have a very hard time suspending my disbelief for super strength. I'm a fan of Disney's John Carter! It's a campy popcorn movie... Drags a little, but you've gotta love the graphics. But if any part of it is science-based then I can duplicate a Picaso painting with my left foot. (Well... Picaso....)
On the other hand, if you're looking for super stamina or endurance... I can suspend my disbelief for that. At least to a point.
Science is a ruthless task master. It really doesn't allow for things like super powers.

Something is off here. $\dfrac{mv^2}{2}$ is energy. It is in joules. Where did per-second came from?

@user58697 "Per second" comes from the fact that the indicated number of joules must be expended each second to keep the object in place. It's a function of converting acceleration to velocity (the "v" in the equation). KE is the energy needed to accelerate a mass to a specific velocity, but the force of gravity is a constant acceleration (otherwise jet packs would be a lot more efficient than they are). Thus, an object traveling 9.8 m/s directly away from the planet must have an engine that maintains that velocity or the object falls to the ground. AKA, energy expended per-second.

Sorry no. The object in place (on the floor, or in my hand, doesn't matter as long as it is in place) needs no joules to be expended. There is zero total force applied to it (so it remains in place), and zero work is done. The mechanics of tiredness is way more complicated.

@user58697 That's factually false. Your body is expending energy holding up the object. The table is experiencing compressive effects holding the object in place. The only way an object can just sit there expending no energy itself nor depending on something else expending energy on its behalf is to be in a perfectly zero-gravity environment. Why on earth do you think you break your leg when you jump off a building? You do realize that Newtonian "equal and opposite" works in both directions, right? For an object not to fall against gravity *something must be holding it up."

... You're not thinking back to your high school physics courses where the net effect of gravity and the flat surface an object sits on is zero and therefore can be cancelled out of the equation, are you? I remember that being used during the early F=mA math on a frictionless surface, but the moment you throw a handful of sand on the surface, it's no longer true and can't be cancelled out.

Yes, muscle atrophy caused by spending a lifetime in lower gravity should cause colonists who grew up in 1g to be stronger than those who grew up in 0.75g doing the same job.
However, in 0.75g, labourer-type workers won't likely be significantly weaker, they will just do more work in the lower gravity, lifting bigger loads than their 1g counterparts in the lower gravity.  In a new colony, manual labour is likely to be one of the major career paths.
So, while the new 1g colonists will likely be stronger than the sedentary workers of the 0.75g colony, they should be about as strong as the colony's labourers... if they are labourers themselves.  1g sedentary workers would probably be weaker than 0.75g labourers.
As for mutation, 500 years is probably not sufficient to make much difference in the baseline strength potential of the old colonists.

It might be worth adding something to drive home the point that in re mutation, fitness selection for being smaller and weaker equals children dying because they were too big and strong.
